# "Apply scale" to object breaks its size when I reload the mesh

Tags: mesh, scale

I'm currently using blender 2.91.0

I was wrapping the UV's of the different objects of my mesh, and in the middle of the process had to apply the scale to some objects so the UVs were sized correctly. After loading my mesh again, the objects that were not at (1, 1, 1) scale (and that I did apply scale to) were all much smaller than normal, and with the scale not applied.

I rolled back to a previous version of my mesh to try replicate the issue, and isolate it to apply scale only. I have the size and scale parameters of the belt object open as an example of the original size. The Horn, Teeth, and Body are all at (1, 1, 1) scale, while the armor and clothing have all different scales. This is the example:

[image: This has the belt selected, and its original scale]

[image: This is after selecting all the objects in the scene, ctrl+A, apply scale. Note the scale of the belt is now (1, 1, 1)]

[image: This is after saving, closing and loading the file. Not only the scale of the belt is back to (0.041, 0.041, 0.041), but it also seemed to apply this rescaling to the belt's dimensions]

The affected objects have an unnaplied multiresolution modifier only. I checked for **Delta Transform** and none of those objects has it. What is happening here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've keyframed your scale at the values `0.041`. You need to re-keyframe them to the values `1.0` (after you've applied scale again). Currently, every time you refresh your blend file, the applied scale of 1.0 is reset to the keyframed values of 0.041.

Comment: Yeah, that was it. I added the keyframes by accident. Cleared them, and now it is working correctly, thank you

Comment: No problem, glad to help!